# dns,gethostaddresses is only returning one ip address

Tags: ip, hostname

I am trying to get all the ip address for an host and need to add those ip to the firewall exception rules. I am using stystem.net dns.gethostaddresses to get the list of IP address. but it is only returning one ip address at any point of time instead of getting all the ip addresses associated to the hostname.

Here is code snippet...

```
IPAddress[] arr=Dns.GetHostAddresses(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Host"].ToString());

            foreach (IPAddress ip in arr)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ip.ToString());
            }
```

Comment: can you show some code ?

Comment: IPAddress[] array = Dns.GetHostAddresses(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["HostName"].ToString());
            foreach (IPAddress ip in array)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ip.ToString());
            }


this is the code i am trying to execute, as per MSDN GetHostAddressses should return ip list, but it doesnt

Comment: I meant, add the code in the question, with proper formating (click help button to see how to format code ...). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are running the code in same computer and it has multiple interfaces with multiple IP Addresses.This code works for me

```
 foreach (NetworkInterface netInterface in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + netInterface.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("Description: " + netInterface.Description);
    Console.WriteLine("Addresses: ");
    IPInterfaceProperties ipProps = netInterface.GetIPProperties();
    foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation addr in ipProps.UnicastAddresses)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(" " + addr.Address.ToString());
    }
    Console.WriteLine("");
  }
```

Comment: Hi Sumeet, i dont need to get the network information. My requirement is, for a given DNS, i need to get all IP addresses and added to firewall exception rule.

Comment: try these but i think it depends on DNS server it is looking for. i tried this code  IPAddress [] temp=  Dns.GetHostAddresses("google.com");

          IPHostEntry temp1=  Dns.GetHostEntry("google.com"); and it returned some time one ip address and another time multiple IP Addresses. nslookup also gave same results

Comment: @Shiva: doc says _If hostNameOrAddress is an IP address, this address is returned without querying the DNS server_, so if `ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Host"].ToString()` is an IP address then it will only return this address and nothing else.

Comment: Thanks to both of you.

@Sumeet, i tried that also it always returns 1 ip address, but it is getting changed sometimes when i run again

Comment: @VB_overflow, i dont have ip address in the config file, i have dns name.

Comment: yes It depends on DNS server. let me know if you want me to update answers and solves your problem..